# How to display image in the simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I am using sqlite database and i have stored the path of image in my sqlite file.
But now I want to display image from the path stored in sqlite file.
for that I have written following code.

```
image_wine.image=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[wineDetail objectForKey:@"wine_photo1"]]];
```

where image_wine is my UIImageView and
wine_photo1 is my sqlite database field where path is stored.

but I am not able to get the image on my simulator when I run the app.
plz tell me how to solve the problem.

thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a very basic mistake. You should assign *UIImage* instance to an *UIImage* object, not an *UIImageView* instance.

```
image_wine.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[wineDetail objectForKey:@"wine_photo1"] ];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
image_wine.image=[[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[wineDetail objectForKey:@"wine_photo1"]] autorelease];
```

or

```
mage_wine.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[wineDetail objectForKey:@"wine_photo1"]];
```

Comment: You are leaking the alloced image, add `autorelease` to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Into an UIImageView the propriety image is rapresented by an UIImage. [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/image)

BTW [wineDetail objectForKey:@"wine_photo1"] is a path? If the image is contained in your project you should use imageNamed: